# Show div at a specific time

Tags: timer

I need to show different divs on different exact times.
Example: **28/11/17 06:00, 08:35, 12:34, 15:21**
The interval is *not* linear and changes daily.
I'd like to show the "08:35 div" until it's 08:35 and then switch to the  "12:34 div".
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please include the content of some example files (only enough lines to illustrate your desire), that show your input and your desired output. Also include some description what you have tried or at least though of sofar.

Comment: Please also specify the technologies used in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When using javascript you can try

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

to get the current time. You can use an if-else statement to manipulate your divs.